# "Exception code: C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION" in progress application, application terminated

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

Progress application terminated during execution. Here is the protrace:

```
Exception code: C0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION
Fault address:  101DA9BF 01:001D99BF C:\Ultra\dlc91e\bin\prow32.dll
```

How to find what program caused this issue? Is there any way to debug and find the problematic code?

Answer (score 2):

If it was a 4gl session that crashed there should be a "procore" or a "protrace" file in the working directory of the session that crashed.  It might also be in the temp directory (specified with the -T startup parameter).

If you can find the protrace file it has a 4gl stack trace which ought to tell you where the problem originated.

Comment: These types of errors are almost always OpenEdge bugs or some outside force (virus scanner, windows version conflict, etc) that caused a crash. You can check for known issues with your version by checking the Progress KB http://knowledgebase.progress.com/pkb_Home

Answer (score 1):

Some notes here:

9.1e is truly ancient. But still Progress has a history of supporting older versions a long time. It's actually set to be ["retired" October 2015](https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1501.openedge-lifecycle-and-platform-availability-guide.aspx).

So if you have an active license you shouldn't hesitate to [contact support](https://www.progress.com/support).

There's also the knowledgebase to search. I found [this](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Gettingerrorthatprowin32exehasstoppedworkingwhenexitinganapplication) that might be something similar. First of all you should think of all things that have changed since the system worked (file system layouts, installation of software like antivirus and firewalls, operating system upgrades, security changes etc etc).

Knowledge base home: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/.

I never use the internal search, I always Google with:

`site:knowledgebase.progress.com`